# Haskell: last digit of a very large number

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to work out the last digit of a very large number. The challenge is that I'm getting the error

```
*** Exception: Prelude.!!: negative index
```

which I don't think should be possible. This happens when I try:

```
lastDigit [27,15,14]
```

Here is my code, which is based on https://brilliant.org/wiki/finding-the-last-digit-of-a-power/:

In this case, n becomes 7 and modList 7 gives the recurring sequence [1,7,9,3,1,7,9,3...], which is the first argument of (!!) in the relevant guard. The second argument of (!!) gives 1 because (y:ys) is (15,14) and rem (powers (15 ^ 14)) 4 is 1. Please help.

```
lastDigit :: [Integer] -> Integer 
lastDigit [] = 1 
lastDigit [x] = x `mod` 10 
lastDigit [x,y] = x ^ y `mod` 10
lastDigit (x:y:ys) 
 | y == 0 && head ys /= 0 = 1
 | n == 0 = 0
 | n == 9 || n == 4 = (!!) (modList n) (rem (fromIntegral $ powers (y:ys)) 2) 
 | n == 2 || n == 3 || n == 7 || n == 8 = (!!) (modList n) (rem (fromIntegral $ powers (y:ys)) 4)
 | otherwise = n
    where n = mod x 10 
         powers xs = foldr1 (^) xs
         modList n = drop 3 . take 30 $ cycle [mod x 10| x <- map (n^) $ take 4 [1..]]
```

Comment: `lastDigit [27,15,14]` gives me `7`.

Comment: Thanks Xia. That should be the answer. Could it be something with my settings? I'm running a 64-bit machine

Comment: Or might there be any Int overflow issues that I have overlooked?

Comment: @Amateur: have you perhaps forgot to reload the file?

Comment: @Willem: I reloaded. That't not the issue. Try: lastDigit [2,11,32] as well and let me know if it works. Getting 'negative index"

Comment: If it matters, I'm using GHC 7.10.3. Is anyone else facing the same issue when they run this code?

Comment: Both test cases?

Comment: Actually no, I tried [2,11,32] now and that didn't work

Comment: Negative index, i hope?

Comment: Yes, if I change `rem` to `mod` that goes away, I might just be masking symptoms here but that seems involved somehow.

Comment: Thanks Harold. This is what I was looking for. It works now!!

Answer (score 1):

You should be very specific about the types, otherwise they might get implicit converted during calculations. If you add Int type to your algorithm, ghc will not complain and run into an negative index exception

```
(fromIntegral $ powers (y:ys)) 2 :: Int)
```

but if you provide

```
(fromIntegral $ powers (y:ys)) 2 :: Integer)
```

it will result in

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Integer’
• In the second argument of ‘(!!)’, namely
    ‘(rem (fromIntegral $ powers (y : ys)) 2 :: Integer)’
```

As you can see you have an implicit Int conversion there. Try to split up your function into smaller ones and provide a type signature, then you should be able to successfully align the types and calculate with Integers instead of Int.

Comment: "Implicit `Int` conversion" isn't quite what's going on -- Haskell has no implicit conversions.  It's just that `(!!)` takes specifically an `Int` as the index, so it forces other type variables to be `Int` when they would otherwise be unconstrained `Num`s and thus defaulted to `Integer`.  This can be confusing for sure.